# Standard Monomials

Tags: algebra

I'm trying to find the number of standard monomials of an ideal.  The footprint bound says (1) that the number of solutions to a system of polynomials is bounded by the number of standard monomials of a Groebner basis for that ideal and (2) if the ideal is radical, then the number of solutions to a system of polynomials for that ideal is equal to the number of standard monomials from the ideal.

```
If[#1 == 1, 1, If[ #1 + #2 == n + 2, -1, 0]] &, {n, n}]
Introduces graded, reversed lexicographic monomial ordering.
numberOfVariables = 2;
vars = x /@ Range[numberOfVariables];
J = {x[1]^2*x[2]^3 - x[2], x[1]^3*x[2] - x[1], x[1]^4 - 
x[2]^3, x[2]^4 - x[1] x[2]^2};
m[f_] := MonomialList[f, vars, 
GrevLex[numberOfVariables]]
(*(m/@J)[[k,1]];Leading monomial of kth element of J*)
LT[Ideal_] := Table[(m /@ J)[[j, 1]], {j, Length[Ideal]}]
LT[J]
e[k_] := Exponent[(m /@ J)[[k, 1]], vars]
e[1]
e[2]
e[3]
e[4](*e[4] GENERALIZES TO e[Length@J]*)
(*multi-exponent of             
x[1]^i*x[2]^j*x[3]^k*...*x[numberOfVariables]^?*)
```

```
temp1[j_Integer] := Module[
  {
   std = {},
   m = Max[Flatten@Join[Table[e[l], {l, Length@J}]]]
   },
  Do[
   Do[
    If[
     PolynomialQ[LT[J][[j]]/(x[1]^a*x[2]^b), vars] ==True,
     std = Join[std, {x[1]^a*x[2]^b}]
     , std = std],
    {a, 0, m - 1}],
   {b, 0, m - 1}
   ]
  ;
  std
  ]
standardMonomials = 
 Table[temp1[l], {l, Length@J}] // Flatten // 
DeleteDuplicates
standardMonomials // Length
```

Looking for a way to use arbitrarily-many variables. As it is, I have one `Do` loop per variable.

Comment: This is no improvement over the prior version of the same question. Actually it's worse, since there is no example with input and desired output. And the last time around there seemed to be two different notion of what are the standard monomials, so the definition will have to be pinned down.

Comment: The best link to go to to find out what standard polynomials are, I’d direct you to this:

Comment: Page two of: https://math.berkeley.edu/~bernd/what-is.pdf. As for an example there are 12 standard monomials for an example which can be found here https://anuragbishnoi.wordpress.com/2018/03/25/the-footprint-bound/ in the example that leads the author to find 12 std monomials whereas my code gives me 14

Comment: Check again. Carefully. The footprint note claims there are two standard monomials. The 12 come from a certain superset. (It is not feasible to give an answer if the question itself is tangled like this.) also you might want to use @… to inform commentators that you have responded— I only came across this by luck.

Comment: Where does it say there are two standard polynomials?  When I read it, I remember it saying the relevant variety had two points, not that there were all 12 standard monomials which is going to equal the number of distinct zeros if the ideal is radical. 
Oh and about tagging you next time; thanks but I know what tagging does and I didn’t want further input from you because you don’t understand the question well enough. I didn’t tag you because I expected zero help with my code from which it is deducible what I am trying to do. And if you are right and it said two sm’s, that means the code shou

Comment: (1) If you want responses you'll need to use @. If you want to lurk and snipe, that's another matter.

Comment: (2) In the example under theorem 1 in the blog it is noted that |ideal footprint|<=|different footprint|=12. So this is an inequality. Moreover it states the number of solutions, per Wolfram|Alpha, is 2. As it happens these solutions do not have multiplicity, so |footprint|=2. And what I denote as |different footprint| is indeed the set of 12 monomials you seem to be fixated upon (they must be REALLY valuable monomials).

Comment: (3) I recently put [CountPolynomialSolutions](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CountPolynomialSolutions/) into the Wolfram Function Repository. It gives the footprint size. It is a straightforward modification to have it show the footprint monomials (exercise left to the reader). It is also straightforward to have it give the 12 monomials you are interested in (hint to reader: skip the Groebner basis computation for that step).

Comment: (4) Okay, that's enough for me. You're the expert. It is beyond my meager discernment why you ever sought assistance from this unworthy forum.